# What’s this bug? Sign of an infestation? Found crawling up the side of my washing machine. [WA]

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Just spotted this bug on the side of my washing machine after putting some dirty clothes in the hamper and transferring a damp load to the dryer. I’m hoping it came in from outside somehow, and isn’t some type of vermin (I live in an apartment and I’m probably the cleanest resident in the building. I’m also paranoid about household pests.) It’s very small, photographed against a damp paper towel. Please tell me this is not a baby roach?

[image]

Comment: Rob Dunn's lab at NCSU does all kinds of neat [projects looking at the diversity of organisms living in people's homes](http://robdunnlab.com/projects/wild-life-of-our-homes/). Possible household organisms includes over 1000 possible insects, and often times more than 100 invertebrates living in single home -- and cleanliness has nothing to do with it! (source: [Michelle Trautwein](https://www.reviewjournal.com/news/science-and-technology/your-home-is-a-gigantic-bug-habitat-and-theres-nothing-you-can-do-about-it/)).

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry, it is definitely not a roach. It is a true bug, Hemiptera. Not a household pest.

Comment: Can you say a few words *how* you know this? What sorts of features allow you to characterize it as *Hemiptera*? Mostly for those of us (me) who know nothing about insect phylogenetics.